# SQL query to calculate shared email address across company field

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build on a query that I got help on here... I need to identify how many email addresses are spread across 3 companies..

[image: sample table]

Here is the results that I am looking to calculate in the dataset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92c3M.png)

```
select company, count(*), count(email_address), count(distinct email_address) 
from "email_DB"
group by company;
```

Above is the current query, I need to be able to calculate how many emails are shared across the company column and how many are just with one company.

Any help would be appreciated. Using Snowflake.

Comment: What results do you want?  What do YOU mean by "email addresses are spread across 3 companies"?

Comment: I need to get a tally by company, how many individuals have emails shared across the three companies.

Comment: Please provide the expected result, it will be easier to help then.

Comment: I am looking to show the companies and how many emails are duplicated 
Company 1 - X# of email Company 2 - X# of Emails Company 3 - X# of emails That are the same, shared across the three, as well as show
Company 1 - X# of emails, Company 2 - X# of emails, etc.. where there is overlap between the email addresses. Does this help @ŁukaszNojek?

Comment: No, it doesn't :). Please just put to the question the answer table you expect to get from the query.

Comment: Total Company 1= X Number     Total Company 2=X Number   Total Company 3=X number

Answer (score 0):

If you want email addresses that are in exactly three companies, then use aggregation and `having`:

```
select email
from "email_DB"
group by email
having count(distinct company) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

First count for each email how many companies use it and then aggregate on the results:

```
select 
  case when counter = 1 then 'just_1' else 'shared' end type,
  count(*) counter
from (
  select email, count(distinct company) counter
  from email_DB
  group by email
) t
group by case when counter = 1 then 'just_1' else 'shared' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution achieved the result step by step, using a WITH clause to create dummy data, so you need to select complete text run, this works in Oracle as it is and if you want to run in Snowflake, you need to tweak little bit. It will give below result

[Image of Result set from the given SQL, executed in Oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX5ee.png)

```
with t as (select 'jeo@jeo.com' Mail, 'ABC' Company from dual
        union all select 'jeo@jeo.com' Mail, 'XYZ' Company from dual
        union all select'jeo@jeo.com' Mail, '123' Company from dual
        union all select'sam@sam.com' Mail, 'XYZ' Company from dual
        union all select'sam@sam.com' Mail, '123' Company from dual
        union all select'bill@bill.com' Mail, 'XYZ' Company from dual
        union all select'no@sharedmail.com' Mail, 'PQR' Company from dual),
    g_CNT(mail,counter) as (Select  mail,COUNT(distinct Company) as counter from t group by mail),
    g_Companies(mail,Company) as (Select    distinct mail, Company from t),
    g_Combinations (mail,Combination, Depth,counter)
        as (Select      c1.mail, c1.Company|| ',' as Combination,       1 Depth,   g_CNT.counter
            From    g_Companies c1,g_CNT where c1.mail=g_CNT.mail
            union all
            Select  c.mail,Combination||Company || ',' as Combination , Depth + 1,    g_CNT.counter
            from    g_Companies c , g_Combinations p,g_CNT
            Where   c.mail=g_cnt.mail and c.mail=p.mail and p.Depth < g_CNT.counter AND     Combination not like '%' || Company || ',%'),
    g_Combinations_2 as (select rownum as r ,mail,trim(Combination) Combination,Depth,counter from g_Combinations where depth>1),
    g_Combinations_3 as (SELECT r,mail,Combination,trim(COLUMN_VALUE) s  FROM g_Combinations_2, xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(Combination, ',', '","') || '"'))),
    g_possible_combs as (select distinct mail,listagg(s,',') within group (order by s) poss_comb from g_Combinations_3 group by R,mail,combination),
-----
    all_CNT as (Select  COUNT(distinct Company) as counter from t),
    all_Companies as (Select    distinct Company from t),
    all_Combinations (Combination, Depth,counter)
        as (Select      c1.Company|| ',' as Combination , 1 Depth, all_CNT.counter From all_Companies c1,all_CNT
        union all
        Select      Combination||Company || ',' as Combination ,    Depth + 1,    all_CNT.counter
        from        all_Companies c ,   all_Combinations p,all_CNT
        Where   p.Depth < all_CNT.counter  AND  Combination not like '%' || Company || ',%'),
    all_Combinations_2 as (select rownum as r ,trim(Combination) Combination,Depth,counter from all_Combinations where depth>1),
    all_Combinations_3 as (SELECT r,Combination,trim(COLUMN_VALUE) s  FROM all_Combinations_2, xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(Combination, ',', '","') || '"'))),
    all_possible_combs as (select distinct listagg(s,',') within group (order by s) poss_comb from all_Combinations_3 group by R,combination),
    Mail_comp_comb as (select Mail,Listagg(Company,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Company) Spread_Across,count(1) Number_Of_Companies from t group by Mail)
select poss_comb Companies_List,max(cnt) Count_of_Shared_Emails from 
(select poss_comb,count(distinct mail) cnt from g_possible_combs group by poss_comb
union all (select a.poss_comb, 0 cnt from all_possible_combs a )
)
group by poss_comb order by 1
```

Comment: This approach seems to hard-code parts of the result, so it can't be used for even very slightly different purposes. Can it be made more general?

Comment: Hi Wibble, There is no hard coding in the SQL , except the dummy data set which I have created initially with multiple unions, we can replace that with actual table. Please let me know your requirement and will try to explain how it works for that requirement.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I took the dummy data as part of the query.